# Auto numbering Wordpress Taxonomy Post Type Category Posts with 0 ahead of it

Tags: wordpress, posts

I want to generate automatically Wordpress taxonomy posts number next to the content like this [image: this picture]. How Can i do it and put 0 for the first 9 posts?

Comment: This is unclear. `taxonomy` and `post` are fundamentally different things in wordpress. Can you be clearer about what you want to do?

Comment: Ok sure.I have Taxonomy Custom post type named Benefites and want to dusplay its posts with the number

Comment: You're working on a theme, I assume. Have you tried to implement this? Please share your code and the exact difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a crazy and simple solution.Here is the code with loop
`<?php $counts = 1 ; ?>
                    <?php
                         $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'benefits', 'posts_per_page' => 1000 ) );
                         while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                             <div class="">
                                <?php if($counts < = 9){
                                    echo '0'.$counts;
                                }else{
                                        echo $counts;
                                    } ?>
                             </div>
                    <?php $counts++; endwhile; ?>`

Comment: This would work, except you're not going to be outputting a number at all once you go past 9. It's not clear from your original question whether you want to output numbers 10+, but if so, you should echo '0' within your if statement, then echo $counts outside it. You'll also want to use <= 9 instead of < 9, otherwise you won't get a zero on number 9.

Comment: Yeah see thx, just updated!In my code I had witten the else statement, forgot to add here too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sprintf function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php, passing in the ID of the post within your loop:

```
<?php
$num_padded = sprintf("%02d", $post->ID);
echo $num_padded;
?>
```

This will only add the zero to the beginning if it's less than the required number of characters (in this case 2).

Comment: Thanks!Tyring to fix the number issue also!

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan `$post->ID` are not going to be consecutive. If you want to do that, you'll need to work with iterations on the loop.